# Using Jquery .data in display divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, I'm trying to create a smooth looking colour selecting div using jquery.

I have the HTML:

```
                <div id="firstSelect"><p onclick="displayFirst()">Colour</p>
                <div id="firstSelectDiv">
                    <div id="beigeDiv">Beige
                    </div>
                    <div id="brownDiv">Brown
                    </div>
                    <div id="creamDiv">Cream
                    </div>
                    <div id="whiteDiv">White
                    </div>
                    <div id="greyDiv">Grey
                    </div>
                    <div id="blackDiv">Black
                    </div>
                    <div id="redDiv">Red
                    </div>
                    <div id="blueDiv">Blue
                    </div>
                    <div id="greenDiv">Green
                    </div>
                    <div id="stripedDiv">Striped
                    </div>
                    <div id="patternedDiv">Patterned
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and the code:

```
function displayFirst(){
$('#beigeDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#brownDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#creamDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#whiteDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#greyDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#blackDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#redDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#blueDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#greenDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#stripedDiv').data('display', 'true');
$('#patternedDiv').data('display', 'true');
if( ?not sure?){
}
```

}

Next I need to use the data assigned to the elements to display the divs. The Divs start out as {display:none;}, but I want to display then using jquery so I can then select only one of them to stay displayed. If that makes any sense.

Basically I'm going to set a .data variable to the divs, then I'm going to select one of them and hide the rest. I need the variable because there is no way of setting the display of them other than a long wided javascript function. Could anyone assist as a way of using the variables in the function to display the elements. I'm kind of new and stuck.

EDIT: I should add I'm very knew with jquery, this site is the first time I am delving into it deeply. Be gentle.

Comment: You just want to always show the next one and hide the others on clicking the button?

Comment: No, I want to click one of them and have it stay selected while the other hide again

Comment: It is not clear what is your expected behaviour. `I want to click one of them and have it stay selected while the other hide again` What do you mean by stay selected? How do you show it in first place? I understand you are looking for showing element on click but as you cannot click hidden element, this is non sense

Comment: I want to click the <p>colour</p>, set the data for each div, then use that data to display the colured divs. Then I can find a way of leaving only one of the divs displayed when it is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/a3aLue2t/

```
// tell jquery to wait for the webpage to finish loading
$(document).ready(function(){

    // select all the divs with a color inside
    var colors = $('#firstSelectDiv > div');

    // when a color is clicked...
    colors.click(function(){

        // hide all the colors
        colors.hide();

        // make sure the clicked color is still visible
        $(this).show();

    });

});
```

edit: and if you want to initially hide your list of colors then you can do this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ezktjts3/1/

make sure you have this CSS to hide your `firstSelectDiv` div:

```
#firstSelectDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

and you can show the div and react to a clicked color as follows:

```
// tell jquery to wait for the webpage to finish loading
$(document).ready(function(){

    // select all the divs with a color inside
    var colors = $('#firstSelectDiv > div');

    // show your colors when "Color" is clicked on the webpage
    $('#firstSelect p').click(function(){
        colors.show();
        $('#firstSelectDiv').css('display', 'block');
    });

    // when a color is clicked...
    colors.click(function(){

        // hide all the colors
        colors.hide();

        // make sure the clicked color is still visible
        $(this).show();

    });

});
```

Comment: Great thanks, that wil help with displaying the one that I want, but what about displaying all of them on click of the firstSelect P.  I'm not that comfortable with the (this)statement yet.

Comment: @A.Wolff He wants the clicked color to stay visible while the other colors are hidden, right? `this` in the handler refers to the DOM element that got clicked, which in this case is the color that was clicked. By doing `$(this)` we can get a jquery selector for this color and we call `.show()` to make sure the clicked color is still visible, since we've just hidden all colors but want the clicked one to remain visible.

Comment: A.Wolff nobody's bad, this website is for learning :)

@TomAlbanese do you want no colors to be displayed initially, then when you click "Colors" you want all the colors to display, and then when you choose a specific colour then you want all other colors to be hidden?

Comment: @Macmee - Thanks for the clarification with my incomplete answer (had a hard time understand the question) +1 from me!

Comment: I suppose I didn't think it through, I also need it to be reversible. Like I need to be able to click on firstSelect again if I want to show them again. It works though. It's the correct answer

Comment: @TomAlbanese just updated my answer to reflect that ^ https://jsfiddle.net/ezktjts3/1/

Comment: Could you offer some more advise please. Next I need to assign a value to a variable based on what was click. I tried var first = $(this).innerHTML, but it returns undefined. Any advise.

Comment: @TomAlbanese try `var first = this.innerHTML` or `var first = $(this).html()`